# regex pattern always return false on glassFish

Tags: regex, glassfish

i have an apply that work fine on tomcat. Today, i have tried to put it on glassfish.
The deploiement fails because 1 regex that is use in my app always returns false on glassfish's server but work fine on tomcat.
I have tried this simple pattern for testing:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("toto");
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

This test fails.
Any solution?

---

i have this pattern that fails on glassfish's server

```
public static boolean isPatternValid(String pattern, String string){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    return m.matches();
}

public static String patternExtension(String extension){
    return "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)("+extension+"))$)";
}
```

I take this regex on http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 3):

you need to repeat the set

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
```

if you use `*` instead of `+`, it will match even if you compare to an empty string.

Comment: ooh, damn, how can i forget this thing ^^. But my problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

[a-z] matches only one character from a to z, adding +  to it will match one or more

```
[a-z]+
```

adding * matches any number of including none.

```
[a-z]*
```